# Overlap SQL with group by

Tags: sql, overlap, sql-server-2017

I have a question regarding overlap in SQL, I have the following structure and data from my database:

```
Table A (Id = uniqueidentifier)
| Name |  StartDate  |    EndDate    | DaysToReceive |
------------------------------------------------------
|   A  |  2019-08-26 |   2020-04-13  | 232           |
|   A  |  2019-12-15 |   2020-04-11  | 119           |
|   A  |  2020-03-06 |   2020-03-31  | 26            |
|   B  |  2020-01-07 |   2020-01-31  | 25            |
|   B  |  2020-02-11 |   2020-02-29  | 19            |
```

I need to get the days to receive, but if there is an overlap I need the difference between the min date and the max date otherwise I use the `DaysToReceive` Summed Column.

I'm trying to get the result to look like this:

```
| Name | DaysToReceive |
------------------------
   A   |     232
   B   |     44
```

I have managed to get this query but only works for overlap days.

```
select DATEDIFF(d, MIN(t1.dt),MAX(t1.enddt)) + 1 as DaysToReceive
from (
    select distinct cp1.dt, min(cp2.dt) enddt
    from ( select StartDate as dt, Id from TableA ) cp1, 
         ( select EndDate as dt from TableA ) cp2
    where cp2.dt > cp1.dt cp1.Id = cp2.Id
    group by cp1.dt
    ) t1, TableA t2
where t2.StartDate between t1.dt and t1.enddt
group by t1.dt, t1.enddt
```

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I would also suggest that you add a db/SQL fiddle.  This is not a trivial problem.

Comment: Are you sure that for `A` value 232 is correct?
how does this: 
`|   A  |  2019-08-26 |   2019-04-13  | 232   |`
 overlaps with 
`|   A  |  2020-03-06 |   2020-03-31  | 26     |`

Comment: @kebek yes it is, because when i save i calc the difference betweeen the start date and end date, but because the `2020-03-06 | 2020-03-31` is inside of the overlap (`2019-08-26 | 2019-04-13`) i don't need this value.

Comment: First and second records for A's start date is after the end date?

Comment: @Srinika, bad tipping. it's 2020.

Comment: Please use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
Select [name], Case when [InRange] = 1 
   then Max(DateDiff(dd, MinStartdate, MaxEnddate) + 1)
   Else
       Sum(DateDiff(dd, Startdate, Enddate) + 1)
   End as [Days]

from
(
Select Distinct a.[name], StartDate, EndDate, MinStartdate, MaxEnddate,
    Case when StartDate > MinStartdate and EndDate < MaxEnddate or 
    (StartDate = MinStartdate and EndDate = MaxEnddate)  then
        1 Else 0  
        End as [InRange]
from
(
SELECT [name], 
   Min(StartDate) AS MinStartdate, Max(EndDate) AS MaxEnddate 
FROM A
Group By [Name]

) Q
inner join A a
on a.[name] = q.[name]
) QQ
```

and here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6b32bb43993fb9da6dd7121cbe9cb4ad)